# Set the value of 10 random non-zero values per row to zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very sparse Pandas DataFrame of ~1,000 rows and ~10,000 columns. Most rows contain only 20-100 non-zero values. I would now like to select any 10 random non-zero values in each row and set their value to 0.

This is my first (very non-Pandas friendly) attempt:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    nonZeros = np.where(row > 0)[0]
    rand = np.random.choice(nonZeros, 10)
    for j in rand:
        df.iloc[i, j] = 0
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us your code.

Comment: @running.t Added code to my question

Comment: Use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method of the dataframe to apply a function to every row of a dataframe (with axis=1).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def setrandom(x):
    counter=10
    while counter>0:
        randindex = np.random.randint(1,10000)
        if x[randindex] !=0:
            x[randindex] = 0
            counter -=1        
    return x

df = df.apply(setrandom, axis=1)
```

this is not really an optimal way of doing it, especially since your dataframe is a sparse one!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer**

You can use the following code:

```
df_with_more_zeros = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(to_replace=x[x!=0].sample(10), value=0), axis=1)
```

Maybe not the fastest way, but a little bit more Pandas friendly

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this is extremely slow. My original method takes ~6 seconds, and I have stopped your method after it didn't finish for at least 60 seconds or so.

Comment: Yes, actually I made a mistake. Look at my edited answer.